# Is there anything different you read in sunah and farz

Tags: salat, sunnah

Do you read the same in sunah and farz apart from the intention of which prayer you are performing?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are differences these are the main differences that come to mind:

- Neither sunnah nor nafl prayers require an adhan or iqamah.
- sunnah and nafl prayers generally are performed as fadd, meaning you should pray them on your own in the best case at home (majority view). It is recommended and emphasized not to pray them in public except for the case of those that can be performed in a congregation or with an imam.
- Except for those sunnah prayers where you may follow an imam all sunnah/nafl prayers are silent prayers.
- All sunnah/nafl prayers except with witr should be performed as a set or sets of two raka'a (majority view).
- Some rulings like standing up for the prayer etc. are regarded more lenient in sunnah or nafl compared to fard prayer.